# What IP is used by APIM during Api import?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I've the following setup. I've Apim with private link + Azure Container App that is part of a Vnet with Nsg. As I cannot add Apim to the Vnet (due to the presence of the private link), I'd like to block all public connections (using the Nsg) to the subnet where the Azure Container App is placed, sp that it can only be accessed via the APIM. So everything works fine, but I've a problem when I try to import Azure Container App to the Apim - even though I've added the Public IP of the Apim as `Allow` in the Nsg configuration, the import fails. If I `open` the Nsg, import works correctly. Additionally, when I import the Api and then `close` the Nsg with the exception of the Apim IP, everything works correctly as well (I can access the API via the Apim, but cannot directly).

Hence my question - what IP is used by the Apim during the Api import ?

Comment: `To import an API in APIM`, we need to add a service tag if that APIM is in NSG. Please confirm whether the service tag was added or not ?"

Comment: Please check the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qn3LR.png)

Comment: Hi, I've added the service tag and I still have the same problem.

Comment: Could you please confirm that ContrainerApp VitualIp was in Internal/External Internal? If the endpoint is an internal load balancer and it won't be accessible. If it's external, it will expose the hosted apps on an internet-accessible IP address. Find a screenshot for reference. https://i.imgur.com/4ZWDzUP.png

Comment: Of course it's publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

APIM uses a special CORS Proxy (https://apimanagement-cors-proxy-prd.azure-api.net/send) Service that is used during the import process so whitelisting it should fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any documentation for that ? I've tried to find some information about that CORS Proxy, but no luck.

Comment: No, just got that from the Developer Tools Network/Console Tab.